# Grails 1.3.9 get service from ApplicationContext

Tags: spring, grails, applicationcontext

Use very old Grails I need to get a service from a static function. This can be done using `ApplicationContext` but from the looks of it this is not supported by Grails. Is there any other way..please help.

```
import grails.util.*


SchedulerService schedulerService = grails.util.Holders.applicationContext.getBean('schedulerService') as SchedulerService
```

Error I get is:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: grails for class: com.digithurst.global.domain.SchedulerService
```

Comment: I've never used such an old version of Grails. Your error is because grails.util.Holders doesn't exist in Grails 1.3.9.

Perhaps try using: http://docs.grails.org/1.3.9/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/ApplicationHolder.html This gives you the grailsApplication statically (it would seem) and from there you can get the bean.

Comment: Grails 1.3.x was a very stable version. Btw, you can try `import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext`

Answer (score 0):

Try with 
`import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ApplicationHolder` to get a bean from the main context.

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder

def schedulerService = ApplicationHolder.application.mainContext.getBean('schedulerService')
```